# Visa question please

Tags: visas

I have a J1 Visa and it expires on 30th June, 2015, and I will renew it on my trip to India.
I am traveling from US through Frankfurt to India.
Will there be any problem in that?

Comment: 30th June 2015 is in the past! Do you mean 2016? Or has it already expired almost a year ago?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I am afraid that as it stands your question does not has enough details to get a useful answer. Can you please add your nationality. But likely the answer you need is already on the site.

Comment: If you are a year in breach as your question suggests, you will not be able to 'renew' your visa in India.  Possible typo? Close voting as 'unclear'.

Comment: @GayotFow having a J-1 visa expiring 11 months ago is no evidence of being in breach.

Comment: I think this question is pretty clear. The OP has a J-1 US visa. It is not uncommon for US visas to expire while the holder is still in legal status. The OP is going to India, where they will apply for a new US visa. In the meantime, they want to transit Frankfurt on the basis of their year-expired J-1 visa. As @phoog points out, there's a decent likelihood this will not work and a transit visa should obtained.

Comment: For me the question is not clear. Either expires should become expired or 2015 should become 2016. Both are one character changes between adjacent keys on the keyboard.
Additional points: nationality (probably Indian, but not stated)? About which "any problem" is the question? The transit in Frankfurt or the visa renewal?

Comment: @GayotFow J-1 entry is valid for the "duration of status", i.e. until the end of the exchange program, as specified on the DS-2019. This could be four months or several years. But that's not really relevant to this question. He seems to just be asking if he can transit Schengen, which we have a very good Q&A on already.

Answer (score 4):

You say your J-1 expired in June 2015.  I assume you are an Indian citizen.

Indian citizens require an airport transit visa to transit in Germany, although there is an exemption if you hold a valid visa for any of several countries, including the United States.  The exemption also applies if you are returning from one of those countries, having used a valid visa to travel there.

It's not entirely clear whether this exemption should include travelers who are returning from a trip using a valid visa, where the return journey falls after the expiration of the visa.  [Advice](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) on the German consular site suggests that you should apply for an airport transit visa:

> **If your resident status has expired, please note:**
>
> The longer the time gap between the expiration date of the visa and the return from the USA, the higher the likeliness of facing complications when transiting through Germany.
>
> The final decision whether an airplane can be boarded or a transit zone can be entered without a transit visa lies with the airlines or German Border Police, respectively. Therefore, the embassy advises clients whose US visa has expired to apply for a transit visa.

(I've changed some of the punctuation and capitalization to conform with English rules; the original has some German-style punctuation.)

Since your visa has expired nearly a year ago, you should no doubt follow this advice.